# Can I use 9V battery to power up a cooler fan?

Tags: voltage, batteries

I am absolutely not an expert in electronics. But I have to make simple circuit: I need to power a cooling fan from a battery.

Right now I have a 12V cooler and 2x 9V batteries. There is no problem to power it up using only one battery, however the current will be too weak to provide sufficient RPMs (maybe even to start).

But using 2x 9V batteries gives 18V that is much higher than expected - I'm afraid it may burn this thing up a little.

As a solution I think I may use 5V cooler (if I can found such in a local stores), using 4xAA batteries (6V in total).

BUT: Some related forums told me that I am able to power up a 12V cooler using red & yellow wire and it's gonna give me 7V. As I am a bit far even from the electronics beginner, the main question is: is this statement correct and what may happen if I use 9V battery for 7V cooler?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please note that a 9V battery will only be able to power a fan for an hour or so, probably even less. The red & yellow wire thing: that is when you want to power a 12 V fan with a lower voltage in a PC, the fan then gets 7V. You're mixing things up, there is no 7V cooler. I suggest you find a 12 V power adapter and use that to power your fan, that will be much easier.

Comment: [Describe your initial problem, not the solution you came up with](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Chances are you can avoid using the fan altogether or power it from something else than batteries.

Comment: If you need one that does X RPM you might want to buy one that does Y RPM at 12V but X RPM at 9V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cooler consume less than 1A (it's writen on it) and if you don't care so much about power consumption, you can use two 9V batteries and LM7812 - it reduces output voltage from 18V to 12V and have only three pins: In (+), Gnd (-), Out (+)
https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf

Comment: Note that a typical 9V battery will last about half an hour at 1A, a questionable lifetime for a cooling fan.

Comment: 1A is only the maximum current for the LM7812. It would only draw as much current as the fan needs. Assuming an 18V supply from 2 batteries, power wise the regulator would be about 67% efficient

Answer (score 0):

You could try a SMPS(Switched-mode power supply) to boost your voltage up to 12V.
Ex: http://www.ti.com/product/lmr61428

Comment: Isn't it an extremely complicated task for me? I have only two days and very few stores where I can buy some stuff.

Comment: What's about the red&yellow connectros? Will it work with 7V?

Comment: Forget about the red & yellow wires, that's when a fan is used in a PC. If you would be using the fan in a PC you could just use the black and yellow wires as these have 12 V, which is perfect for your fan !

Comment: If you mean to boost the 9V battery voltage to 12V, that's actually going to increase the current drained on the battery (if the load is R, the current drained @ 9V is 9/R, and @ 12V it is more than 12²/(9R)=16/R). If the motor didn't start because the voltage was insusfficient that might work, but if it didn't because the battery couldn't provide the current it won't.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple as possible:

Just go out and get 8 x AA batteries, slap them in series, attach red to positive and black to negative (dw about yellow) and you got a good 12V power supply. Forget 9v batteries as they tend to have a lower energy density, AAs are a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted it to have a greater cooling time you may consider a small sealed lead acid 12v battery. They are heavy though which is an issue with portable cooling.